# Wordpress exibir a url da imagem da foto do author do post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Galera alguém aqui sabe me dizer como faço para pegar a url da imagem da foto do author ou administrador do post no wordpress ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foto do autor é também chamada de *avatar*.

Para mostrar o avatar dentro do [loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) do Wordpress é assim:

`<?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 32 ); ?>`

O primeiro parâmetro é o e-mail, id do usuário/autor ou um objeto de post.
O segundo parâmetro é opcional e representa o tamanho da imagem com o máximo sendo 512 e o padrão sendo 96.

Se preferir somente a url da imagem use a função `get_avatar_url`.
O primeiro parâmetro é similar ao `get_avatar`. O segundo parâmetro é um vetor e aceita diversas chaves de valores sendo *size* para o tamanho.

Exemplo:

`<?php echo get_avatar_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), ['size' => 32] ); ?>`

Para mais exemplos veja na documentação oficial das funções.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_url/